# Using "become: true" to change default shell with Ansible not working

Tags: shell, ubuntu, ansible

Using `become` to change the default shell for a user is not giving the intended result. Using:

```
- name: Change default shell to zsh
  shell: sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

`/etc/passwd` looks like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/usr/bin/zsh
```

Which is the intended result, i.e., changing the default shell for the `ubuntu` user to `zsh`. Now, I'd rather use `become`:

```
- name: Change default shell to zsh
  become: true
  shell: chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

But then `/etc/passwd` looks like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/usr/bin/zsh
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
```

**Notice that `zsh` was set for `root` only.**

What am I missing here? Isn't `become: true` plus `shell: chsh -s $(which zsh)` the same as `sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)` or `sudo chsh -s $(which zsh)`?

If I add `$(whoami)` like:

```
- name: Change default shell to zsh
  become: true
  shell: chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

I get the same, `root` with `zsh` but not the user I want to change.

Comment: In the first code, `whoami` is executed before `sudo`, so `root` is running `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh ubuntu` (i.e., the command substations run as you before `sudo` runs a command constructed from the results.) With `become`, the entire command line, including the command substitutions, is run as root. I'm not sure there is a simple way to do this without using multiple ... plays? (I'm fuzzy on Ansible terminology) to determine the user and shell before actually running `chsh` as `root`.

Comment: That is, `become: True` makes you run something equivalent to `sudo sh -c 'chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)'`.

Comment: Ok so I guess I could just run and register the output of `whoami` in a task and then use that output in the next task with `become`. I'll give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: (Task, that's the word I was looking for :) )

Comment: Worked like a charm! will post it as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
- name: Register current user (workaround to change default shell)
  shell: whoami
  register: current_user

- name: Change default shell to zsh
  become: true
  shell: "chsh -s $(which zsh) {{ current_user.stdout }}"
```

See the comments above for the details. In short, I had to run `whoami` first so that the right user was used when running `chsh`.

Comment: I'm happy that it worked for you but I would do with `command` module as it's preferred over shell.

On the other hand, I think that if you want to change user configuration like Default Shell it might be better to use `user` module instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this:

```yaml
- name: Ensure the user 'ubuntu' has a zsh shell.
  user:
    name: ubuntu
    shell: /bin/zsh
    state: present
  become: yes
```

Comment: I was trying to a avoid declaring the user as I don't know the username beforehand.

Comment: Good point, but you can also declare the name as variable if that suits you better. Just to provide more flexibility that all the users created with that play will have the same settings.